# Maven define goal dependencies, run initialize before versions:set

Tags: maven, properties, dependencies, versioning

I'm including a newVersion propery form an external file using:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
  <!-- Read in newVersion.properties instead of newVersion property -->
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <files>
          <file>${session.executionRootDirectory}/newVersion.properties</file>
        </files>
      </configuration>
    </execution> 
</plugin>
```

I'm also using versions:set to set the new version of the code from a CI build.

This works if I run:

```
mvn -DBUILD_NUMBER=99 initialize versions:set
```

IOW, I need to specify the "initialize" goal explicitly or it stops and prompts me for the newVersion because it defaults to running the versions:set goal before initialize goal.

How can I define the initialize goal as a dependency of the versions:set goal?

IMO I should not need to define intermediate target ordering.

Note, I know I could use the versions plugin to do all of this but I need to manage gradle and maven versions from a parent gradle script, so I need the base newVersion to come from an external source so that I can use it from multiple build environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re `mvn ... initialize ...` – You bound the `read-project-properties` goal of the `properties-maven-plugin` to the `validate` phase, so `mvn validate` should be sufficient. ([Introduction to the Build Lifecycle, Default Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)).

Invoking `mvn ... versions:set` without any phase executes the `set` goal of the `versions` plugin directly without passing through (any phase of) the default lifecycle. That means it doesn't „*default to running the versions:set goal before initialize*“, it doesn't pass the `initialize` phase (`initialize` is a *phase* not a goal) at all.

And there's also the following at [Versions Maven Plugin, Basic Usage](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html):

> Maven 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and 3.0 do not currently support re-reading modifications of the `pom.xml` within one invocation of Maven.
>
> The following goals:
>
> - **versions:set**
> - **...**
>
> modify the `pom.xml` file, you need to run these goals separately from any other goals or life-cycle phases.

I'm not aware of any way to define a phase as dependency of a goal but you can declare:

```
<build>
  <defaultGoal>...</defaultGoal>
```

> - **defaultGoal:** the default goal or phase to execute if none is given. If a goal is given, it should be defined as it is in the command line (such as jar:jar). The same goes for if a phase is defined (such as install).

See [POM Reference, The BaseBuild Element Set](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element).

Comment: Sigh. One more reason to migrate to gradle. Thanks for the detailed answer Gerold.

Comment: @Bruce Do you know that this is easier with Gradle? I don't. I've never had a task I couldn't fulfilll with Maven, so I've never had a reason to migrate to something else. What about declaring profiles in your[`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) or in your [POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles): 1) _dev_ (set as active by default) for your normal project work and 2) _setVersion_ that binds `versions:set` to the `initialize` phase (which also assures that `read-project-properties` bound to `validate` is executed before).

Comment: @Bruce See also [my answer to _Maven: Lifecycle vs. Phase vs. Plugin vs. Goal_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774) for what it's all about with the named Maven entities.

Comment: I've been working with gradle & maven side by side for a couple of years now. I'm not a maven expert (or a gradle one for that matter), but I favor gradle as it's groovy plus a DSL specific to processing inputs into outputs with plugins added for specifics. The fact that it is based on groovy makes the unusual cases easier to handle as extension is a natural part of the process. I've gotten mileage from the groovy-maven-plugin plugin, but it's less functional that extending via groovy as needed. For the above case with gradle, I would declare a dependsOn clause to force the ordering.

Comment: @Bruce You know you can extend Maven by [writing own plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/index.html) entirely in Groovy, do you?

Comment: I hadn't ever been that deep into maven.  I guess that's the difference with gradle is that you're in a more customizeable environment by default whereas with maven you have to make it explicit. As I mentioned, not a maven expert. Thanks for the pointer though, I can see the benefits of that. In fact it may help with the gradle/maven integration I still need to do.