# How To find the license and dependency version used in a maven project?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I need to find the dependencies license and version information used in the maven project. We are using both maven2 and maven3. Could you please let me know how it can be done?

It would be great if you can show me the steps and how to invoke the target as well?

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: How to invoke which „_target_“? Maven has _phases_ and _goals_ that can be invoked. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774) to _Maven: Lifecycle vs. Phase vs. Plugin vs. Goal_ for the proper terminology and the meanings.

Answer (score 0):

A dependency's version is declared in the project's POM (`pom.xml`). See [POM Reference, Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).

A dependency's license info – if there is any – is declared in the dependency's POM. Go to [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/), if the dependency resides there → search for the dependency's *groupId* or *artifactId* → select the *pom* link in the *Download* column.

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to iterative all the POMs in the project to find the depenendcy license information?

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to parse all the POMs to extract the dependencies license information?

Comment: @user2586964 See the [Reports Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) or the [License Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/).