# How do I add a directory in /target to the resulting JAR with Spring Boot?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, static-content, enunciate

I'm using [Enunciate](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate) to generate REST documentation upon building a REST application. Enunicate outputs documentation to `/target/docs`. I would like to add the `/docs` directory to the resulting JAR file (and rename it) to be able to serve docs as static content.

How do I do this? I can't figure out how to get these static files (which are generated upon build) into the JAR.

Comment: I think you will want to add these to your resources/static directory inside your jar correct? Otherwise you can't serve them up. How about copying them using a Maven Ant command after a certain goal?

Comment: Closely related to 'Maven: Lifecycle vs. Phase vs. Plugin vs. Goal' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607834/maven-lifecycle-vs-phase-vs-plugin-vs-goal/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can solve this by configuring the [Maven plugin for enunciate](https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Executables#maven) and wiring it up to be run in the 'generate-resources' lifecycle phase.

Also, make sure you set the output-dir to a subdirectory of src/main/resources/static, as commented by Rob above.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my enunciate.xml to force the docs directory to be generated in a custom location which will be packaged with the .war file

```
<docs docsDir="target/<app_name>/docs"/>
```

and then maven will put the entire contents of target/ into the resulting war file package