# Manage multiple dependencies between microservices using Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies, release, microservices

We are using Maven to define and manage our dependencies between our microservices. Here is an example:

**Microservice 1**

```
<artifactId>ms-1</artifactId>
<version>0.25.04-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>ms-2</artifactId>
        <version>0.25.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Microservice 2**

```
<artifactId>ms-2</artifactId>
<version>0.25.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>ms-3</artifactId>
        <version>0.28.00-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The problem is that the release phase is taking a lot of time and is fully manual:

1. perform `mvn:release` for the first microservice (removes `-SNAPSHOT`)
2. change the version in `pom.xml` of the dependency
3. perform `mvn:release` for the second microservice (removes `-SNAPSHOT`)
4. and so on (actually on 15 microservices...)

I'm wondering if there is any automatized way to perform this release (in cascade)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Maven project is not in charge of managing the versions of its dependencies. It's the project that builds a dependency artifact that's responsible for its version.

In your case you could create a (pseudo-)aggregator project that includes all your microservices as sub-modules:

```
<modules>
    <module>../ms-1</module>
    <module>../ms-2</module>
    <module>../ms-3</module>
    <module>../...</module>
    <module>../ms-15</module>
</modules>
```

Assuming that your microservice projects are siblings to each other like:

```
+- (pseudo-)aggregator
|  +- pom.xml
+- ms-1
|  +- pom.xml
+- ms-2
|  +- pom.xml
+- ms-3
|  +- pom.xml
+- ms-...
|  +- pom.xml
+- ms-15
   +- pom.xml
```

If they are not adapt the relative `<module>`s paths accordingly.

Such you are asked for the release versions of all of the projects (default is current `<version>` minus `-SNAPSHOT`, to be confirmed by just <kbd>Enter</kbd>)  during a `.../(pseudo-)aggregator $ mvn`[`release:prepare`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html), which also updates your `<dependencies>/<dependency>/<version>`s accordingly.

Or you can perform a [non-interactive release](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html) with `-B | --batch-mode` which uses the defaults without asking.

And finally an amendment:

`release` is not a *phase* of [Maven's build lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). It's the shortcut for the [`maven-release-plugin`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-release-plugin%22) that has various [*goals*](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html).

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know about Maven aggregator. Let me rephrase to check if I'm right. You suggest I create a dedicated POM project, which defines all my microservices as module, and then call the maven goals to perform a release?

Comment: @frinux That's right. See [POM Reference, Aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) and [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit) for basic information. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774) for how phases, plugins, goals, etc. work together.

Comment: There is a detail I forgot to mention: the microservices consume each other through a JAR (HTTP client) which is generated, but doesn't exist at the moment of the maven release. It seems it is impossible to declare a module if it doesn't exist at the build time, am I wrong?

Comment: I guess I'm hitting a limit of our architecture : we are coupling microservices between them when we generate API clients. Maybe the right way is to use an AMQP?

Comment: @frinux You're right, you can't declare a module that doesn't exist. But you can create a placeholder module that contains just a `pom.xml` with `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>`, `<version>`as sole content for the time being.

Comment: Thanks I managed by creating a real project for each microservice, and to declare them all modules of a pseudo-project "release" which can now perform release for each microservices.