# Can I resume a Maven lifecycle from an arbritrary phase?

Tags: java, maven, continuous-delivery

I would like to convince Maven to "continue where it left off". I first do a `mvn package` to build the package. At a later time I may want to continue the lifecycle to do the integration test etc. by doing a `mvn install`. In this case I would prefer Maven not to start the lifecycle all over again from the start, but to actually resume at the first phase after `package` (i.e. `pre-integration-test`). Is it possible to start the lifecycle at a phase other than the first one?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. [See also this mail](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Execute-only-a-specific-phase-td103134.html).

Comment: i know that mvn install do: "validate", "compile", "package" and "verify" before doing the "install", so, actually i don't know if is possible tho override this, cause overwrite this setting should be the only way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no built-in functionality that supports this. You can, however do the following:

Overwrite all goal bindings up to (but excluding) the intended starting phase that come from:

- [`default-bindings.xml`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=maven.git;a=blob;f=maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml)
- `<build>/<plugins>/<plugin>` sections of the current and all parent POMs (check with `mvn help:effective-pom`)

in a [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>resume-at-pre-int-test</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-echo-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>skip-process-resources</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>echo</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <echos>
                            <echo>Default plugin:goal binding for process-resources phase overridden</echo>
                        </echos>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    ...
                </plugin>

                ...

            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Activate it with `mvn install -P resume-at-pre-int-test`.

Comment: Can I also just un-bind goals?

Comment: @Rinke Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Rinke Just an idea: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774) you can try to tweak `<Your Maven installation>/lib/maven-core-x.y.z.jar/META-INF/plexus/default-bindings.xml` accordingly, but I haven't tried this myself yet.