# Maven build fails inside IntelliJ and on command line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-3

I have searched high and low to find a resolution for this and I am stumped.

I'm trying to build from the *google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all* archetype and continue to get the same error within IntelliJ and using `mvn install` using POM on command line. Also get the same error using `mvn archetype:generate ...` from command line.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli)
on project standalone-pom: The defined artifact is not an archetype -> [Help 1]
```

Hoping somebody else has seen this.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
  </parent>
 
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
  <name>Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java - All</name>
  <description>Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java is a distribution of Apache
      Beam designed to simplify usage of Apache Beam on Google Cloud Dataflow
      service. This artifact includes entire Dataflow Java SDK.</description>
 
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
 
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
 
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

mvn generate:archetype command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.cloud.dataflow \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0 \
-DgroupId=com.rgault.google \
-DartifactId=dataflow \
-DinteractiveMode=false \
-Dpackage=com.rgault.google \
-Dversion=0.1
```

Comment: Please add the _complete_ command line you entered and the POM you used to your question.

Comment: I'll add them into the original post, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use an archetype which is not actually one, but an [all-in-one dependency bundle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.dataflow/google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all/2.0.0):

> **Google Cloud Dataflow SDK For Java All » 2.0.0**
>
> Google Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java is a distribution of Apache Beam designed to simplify usage of Apache Beam on Google Cloud Dataflow service. This artifact includes entire Dataflow Java SDK.

As per [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven), the correct archetype id is `google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples`:

> Create a Maven Project that contains the Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java and Examples
>
> 1. Create a Maven project containing the Cloud Dataflow SDK for Java using the Maven Archetype Plugin. Run the `mvn archetype:generate` command in your shell or terminal as follows:
>
>    JAVA: SDK 1.X
>
>    ```
>        mvn archetype:generate \
>        -DarchetypeArtifactId=google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples \
>        -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.cloud.dataflow \
>        -DarchetypeVersion=1.9.0 \
>        -DgroupId=com.example \
>        -DartifactId=first-dataflow \
>        -Dversion="0.1" \
>        -DinteractiveMode=false \
>        -Dpackage=com.example
>    ```
>
>    JAVA: SDK 2.X
>
>    ```
>        mvn archetype:generate \
>        -DarchetypeArtifactId=google-cloud-dataflow-java-archetypes-examples \
>        -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.cloud.dataflow \
>        -DarchetypeVersion=2.0.0 \
>        -DgroupId=com.example \
>        -DartifactId=first-dataflow \
>        -Dversion="0.1" \
>        -DinteractiveMode=false \
>        -Dpackage=com.example
>    ```

Comment: Thank you for this. Still wrapping my head around Maven.

Comment: @R.Gault See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774) for a few of the basic concepts and for links to good references/books.