# Why `maven-site-plugin` present in maven java project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I just created an empty Maven project using ***Intellij*** and ran `mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`.

```
Plugin Resolved: maven-site-plugin-3.3.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-reporting-exec-1.1.jar
[INFO]     Plugin Dependency Resolved: maven-core-3.0.jar
```

pom.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>    
</project>
```

**Update:**
I have tried `effective-pom` as suggested and here is result.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.1:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
    <version>3.3</version>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.1:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
    // some other config
</plugin>
```

As I haven't specified anywhere about this plugin (`maven-site`) or (`maven-core`), finding it difficult to understand.

Why is the Maven site plugin present along with other plugins, and how do I remove it?

Comment: Do you have a parent POM?

Comment: No parent pom @JFMeier, updated above.

Comment: Did you have a look at the effective POM?

Comment: it is there in effective-pom, but still not getting why it's being added. @JFMeier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is brought in by Maven's internal [definition of the `site` lifecycle](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.6.1/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml#L88):

```
        <default-phases>
          <site>
            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site
          </site>
          <site-deploy>
            org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:deploy
          </site-deploy>
        </default-phases>
```

It's not part of your pom, or any parent pom.

The `effective-pom` output you show has a pointer to the source, in `org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.1:default-lifecycle-bindings`:

```
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.1:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
    <version>3.3</version>  <!-- org.apache.maven:maven-core:3.6.1:default-lifecycle-bindings -->
```

Comment: I was checking this https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging. couldn't find plug-in in default binding.   Can you please help explaining that part if possible ?

Comment: `site` is its own lifecycle, not a type of packaging for the `default` lifecycle. See [Lifecycles Reference - `site` Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle).

Comment: Basically what my understanding is "each packaging has default plugin binding" and then  "each plugin has it's own lifecycle". So, i am still not able to understand if plugin is not part of default binding of packaging, why it's coming as part if default-lifecycle binding. Please correct me if i mis understood something.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607834/maven-lifecycle-vs-phase-vs-plugin-vs-goal for some guidance on the difference between lifecycles (`default`, `clean` and `site`) and the different packaging types that associate goals with the `default` (i.e. regular build) lifecycle.