# Is there a way to build a project for different client with the same base but with modularity for some feature that would be discovered at runtime?

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I'm used to using the E4 Eclipse framework to build desktop applications and now I would like to migrate to a simple maven project.

In the Eclipse platform with OSGi, there is a notion of bundle, feature and product.

When I want to build my project for client A, I have a file A.product describing all the dependencies. For client B, I have B.product and so on.

Of course, my software shares the same base, but if a client wants a new feature (like a plugin) I have to add it to my product file, and the new feature will be discovered at runtime and present to my software.

In maven, I don't find a good way to do the same things, because there is only one pom.xml describing the whole project. How can I introduce modularisation for plugin discovered at runtime?
Should I have multiple POM for each client?
Should I use the profile to do that? I tried but I was not easy to manage.

Is there another maven good way to do it, and to manage the variability easily?

Comment: Have you seen [Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) already?

Comment: Yes I saw tycho but I would like to leave the e4 world and come in the more normal maven way. 

My need are not about desktop app, so I’m using quarkus with cdi for injection. 

I would just like to variabilize my Pom.xml. One for client A with N plugins discovered at runtime. And (maybe) another Pom.xml (or profile ?) for client B with N’ Plug-ins discoverer at runtime.

Comment: You tagged your question with [osgi]. The Tycho main page reads: „_Tycho is a set of Maven plugins and extensions for building [...] OSGi bundles with Maven._“. Maybe there's some other way to build (web or backend or local, not Eclipse) applications based on OSGi with Maven but I haven't seen any other so far.

Comment: You're right. I just removed the [osgi] tag, before actually, what i'm looking for is to remove the osgi way.

Basically, the question is just : how can create a basic deployment with just A.jar. For example A.jar declare an interface Plugin and i have one implementation of this interface in B.jar and another implementation in C.jar.

At the end, i would like to create 2 products. One with A.jar and B.jar, and another one for example with A.jar and C.jar, or A.jar with B.jar and C.jar.

Should i create one pom.xml for each deployment ? Or is there a better maven way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re „*And (maybe) another Pom.xml (or profile ?)*“ in one of your comments to the question:

One of Maven's principles is: *one* project (declared in a POM), *one* resulting (main) artifact ([JAR, WAR, ...](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#packaging)). („main“ since there can be accompanying artifacts like [`...-sources.jar`, `...-javadoc.jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html), [`...-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, `....zip`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html), ...)

Maven POMs are of declarative nature. That means, there are no (imperative) `if`s to skip declarations on occasion and you also can't add/remove declaration (XML) elements during build (you "just" can add/change element text contents via [properties](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)). (There are plugins with a `<skip>false|true` parameter, which can be set/overridden with a property, but that's not a general rule and therefore there are not many of them.)

[Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) are a way to overcome this no-if-principle. With them you can [activate ("inject") declarations](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html#Profiles_in_POMs) which set or override existing declarations at build time via [various profile activation methods](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#activation).

Regarding your comment after removing the <kbd>osgi</kbd> tag, I'm going to update this answer later. In the meantime you can have a look at my answer to [Maven: Lifecycle vs. Phase vs. Plugin vs. Goal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774).

### UPDATE

```
+- jojal-main
   +- pom.xml   ... contains declarations common for all of your projects
   +- base-main
      +- pom.xml   ... contains declarations common for all base projects
      +- A
         +- src/main/java/your/package/Plugin.java
         +- pom.xml
      +- B
         +- src/main/java/your/package/ClassA.java   ... implements Plugin
         +- pom.xml
      +- C
         +- src/main/java/your/package/ClassB.java   ... implements Plugin
         +- pom.xml
   +- product-main
      +- pom.xml   ... contains declarations common for all product projects
      +- product1
         +- src/main/java/your/package/Product1.java   ... references A & B
         + pom.xml
      +- product2
         +- src/main/java/your/package/Product2.java   ... references A & C
         +- pom.xml
      +- product3
         +- src/main/java/your/package/Product3.java  ... references A & B & C
         +- pom.xml
```

#### jojal main POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <groupId>name.jojal</groupId>
  <artifactId>jojal-main</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>  <!-- different to the default 'jar'[1] -->

  <modules>  <!-- to build projects in sub-dirs at once[2] -->
    <module>base-main</module>
    <module>product-main</module>
  </modules>

  ... declarations common for all of your projects like dependencies for unit testing, logging etc. ..

<project>
```

<sup>[1]</sup> [POM Reference, Packaging](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#packaging)
<sup>[2]</sup> [POM Reference, Aggregation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation)

#### Base main POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>   <!-- declarations are inherited from this parent POM[3] -->
    <groupId>name.jojal</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>jojal-base-main</artifactId>  <!-- <groupId>, <version> can be omitted if the same as in parent -->
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
  </modules>

  ... declarations common for all base projects ...

<project>
```

<sup>[3]</sup> [POM Reference, Inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance)

#### A POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>
    <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-base-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
 
  <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>

<project>
```

#### B POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>
    <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-base-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<project>
```

#### C POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>
    <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-base-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
 
  <artifactId>project-c</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<project>
```

#### Product main POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>
    <groupId>name.jojal</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>jojal-product-main</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>product1</module>
    <module>product2</module>
    <module>product3</module>
  </modules>

  ... declarations common for all product projects ...

<project>
```

#### Product 1 POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>
    <groupId>name.jojal.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-product-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>product-1</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>  <!-- project-a is resolved automatically by Maven
                                               as a transitive dependency[4] -->
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<project>
```

<sup>[4]</sup> [POM Reference, Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#dependencies)

#### Product 2 POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>
    <groupId>name.jojal.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-product-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>product-2</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-c</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

<project>
```

#### Product 3 POM

```xml
<project ...>
  ...

  <parent>
    <groupId>name.jojal.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>jojal-product-main</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>product-3</artifactId>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>name.jojal.base</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-c</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

<project>
```

[Please note: Not tested in real, typos possible]

Comment: Wow great answer ! It is exactly what i would like to achieve.
Thank you for this great answer with a lot of details and references.

Comment: Is there a way to skip the build of all the products when we do "mvn clean package" at the jojal-main ? If i ask this question it's to avoid to rebuild all client project each time.

Maybe another idea would be to split in different repository ?

Comment: You're welcome. Change into the dir `/base-main` and run `mvn ...` there. Only the modules declared in POM `jojal-base-main` will be built then. And this also applies to "leaf" projects, generally every project, in the tree: Change to dir `B`, run `mvn ...` there and only `project-b` will be built. An alternative is [`mvn -f /path/to/pom.xml`](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html) from anywhere.

Comment: Great, everything works perfectly now. Thank you for your help.
My last problem with maven is to share my application.properties which is in the base-main in all products to share a global configuration, but i think it's out of scope of the initial problem :)

Thank you again. Very helpful.