# How to fix import error on Maven in Eclipse? Value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am having problem when importing existing maven projects into Eclipse. Every time i get the following error:

> Could not get the value for parameter encoding for plugin execution default-resources
>
> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.1.0 -> org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:3.1.1 -> org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.0.0

As the project imports thru, the only error that shows up is in pom.xl on parent tag.

I have tried to completely uninstall Java, Maven and Eclipse. None of this worked for me.

This is how the pom.xl file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>Pr1.pr1</groupId>
<artifactId>pr1p</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>pr1p</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**UPDATE**: After reinstalling Maven once again, repairing wrongly defined system variables and rebooting PC, it just works. I am unsure which of these fixed the problem, most likely the reinstallation.

Comment: Please check to build on plain command line....

Comment: UPDATE: After reinstalling Maven once again, repairing wrongly defined system variables and rebooting PC, it just works. I am unsure which of these fixed the problem, most likely the reinstalation.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Maven project with your POM here. I added to it:

```xml
        ...
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>igb.so.DemoApplication</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        ...
```

`$ mvn clean install`

```text
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.707 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-02T21:26:35+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And, BTW, for the [Maven Compiler plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release) it's:

```xml
    <properties>
        ...
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>
```

I added that, too.

Re [`java.version`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()):

> **API Note:**
>
> **Changing a standard system property may have unpredictable results unless otherwise specified.**

The [`resources-plugin` ist the first in the default build lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028475/1744774). Are there special `<servers>`/[`<mirrors>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) declarations in your [`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)?

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference. Actual error is `Failed to collect dependencies` so most likely misconfigured settings.xml