# Include unzipped resource in JAR - Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a versioned ZIP file deployed in my artifact repository that I need to download, extract, and include as a resource with Maven.

I have been successful using the `maven-dependency-plugin` to retrieve the artifact and extract it during the `package` phase with the `unpack` goal. I see the extracted ZIP where I want it in the build directory. I then have that unpacked directory included as a resource. I can see the directory getting included with the appropriate files inside of the `source-jar/myProject-sources.jar`. I do not see this folder included in the final JAR `myProject.jar`.

Any suggestions or examples on how to include this extracted resource would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extract during the `package` phase that's long after the `process-resources` phase [when the `maven-resources-plugin`'s `resources` goal runs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028475/1744774) by default:

[image: Maven Lifecycles, Phases, Goals, Plugins]

> [**resources:resources**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) copies the resources for the main source code to the main output directory.
>
> This goal usually executes automatically, because it is bound by default to the process-resources life-cycle phase. It always uses the project.build.resources element to specify the resources, and by default uses the project.build.outputDirectory to specify the copy destination.

I'd try to extract at the `generate-resources` phase.

Comment: My IDE was marking unpack with the error of 'Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration' when I had previously tried to change the phase.  I ignored it and compiled from the command prompt; works just fine with your suggestion.

Comment: @bkstradling In Eclipse I can _Ignore_ these messages in _Preferences_ → _Maven_ → _Error/Warnings_ or edit the _lifecycle mappings metadata_ file in _Maven_ → _Lifecycle Mappings_.