# The jar file provided by Maven repository does not include class files

Tags: maven, find-sec-bugs

I need to use [BaseDetectorTest](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/blob/master/findsecbugs-test-util/src/test/java/com/h3xstream/findbugs/test/BaseDetectorTest.java) provided from one of Spotbugs extension library

I added the maven dependency from ([FindBugs Test Utility](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h3xstream.findsecbugs/findbugs-test-util))

But it does not include the BaseDetectorTest class file (Once Maven is updated, the jar file is added to the external libraries - but not the class file).

I am wondering why it happens.

My guess is "the Jar file provided by the repository is still being developed"

Could you teach me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[`find-sec-bugs/findsecbugs-test-util/src/test/java/com/h3xstream/findbugs/test/BaseDetectorTest.java`](https://github.com/find-sec-bugs/find-sec-bugs/blob/master/findsecbugs-test-util/src/test/java/com/h3xstream/findbugs/test/BaseDetectorTest.java) is a test class. `.../src/test/...` and `...Test.java` are indicators for that. Test classes aren't included in a project's JAR (by the `jar:jar` goal of the [Maven JAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/) which is the default binding for the [`package`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028475/1744774) phase) but in a project's `...-tests.jar` which is created by the `jar:test-jar` goal.

1. On [MvnRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h3xstream.findsecbugs/findbugs-test-util) select a version tag, e.g. [<kbd>1.9.0</kbd>](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h3xstream.findsecbugs/findbugs-test-util/1.9.0), then **Files** <kbd>jar (2 KB)</kbd> [View All](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h3xstream/findsecbugs/findbugs-test-util/1.9.0) to find the `...-tests.jar`. Use it with:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h3xstream.findsecbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>findbugs-test-util</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.0</version>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

2. On Maven Central you can get a later version ([1.11.0](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.h3xstream.findsecbugs/findsecbugs-test-util)), select it and then [Browse](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/h3xstream/findsecbugs/findsecbugs-test-util/1.11.0/)  to find it. Use it with:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h3xstream.findsecbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>findsecbugs-test-util</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.0</version>
  <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. I solved it. I can use the test class as well. Thank you.

Comment: @YoochulKim If an answer to your own question is satisfying you also can _accept_ it. See [Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)