# Non-parseable POM bug in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

This is my POM:

[image]

Aparently all my tags are well closed but I keep reciving the error:

[image]

The error only appears when I place the `<build>...</build>` snippet, otherwhise I'm good to go, but I need that code in order to compile the program.
I'm using eclipse Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0) Build id: 20210612-2011

Comment: It is easier to help if you include the pom (or a reproducible part of it) as text. Also note that Eclipse can be a bit buggy with pom files. If you can build from a command prompt (mvn clean package) things are probably fine anyway.

Comment: Welp, i tryed to pass it as code but it wouldnt catch the whole archive but just the first line, so i decided to pass it as a photo instead.
Anyway how do I do the build from prompt? I'm on Windos, my project is located on (C:\Users\Usuario\eclipse-workspace\app_Tfg) 
Sorry for my lack of basic knowdelge...

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774) See also [Code and Preformatted Text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [Syntax highlighting for code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Comment: You can perform a Maven build from within Eclipse as well (with the default Maven version embedded in Eclipse or with the Maven installation on your HDD, if configured/added accordingly): _Right-click_ the project or the `pom.xml` in the _Package_ or _Project Explorer_ view→ _Run As_ → _Maven_ \[...6 options... [_install_ is the "biggest"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Default_Lifecycle)].

Comment: See this [answer to _Maven: Lifecycle vs. Phase vs. Plugin vs. Goal_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953905/1744774) for basic Maven knowledge and, of course, https://maven.apache.org/.