# Maven: How is a phase mapped to a lifecycle

Tags: maven

i'm wondering about how Maven maps a phase to a lifecycle.

For example when running

```
mvn clean
```

then Maven executes the phases "pre-clean" and "clean" of the "clean" lifecycle.

But how does Maven determine that the phase "clean" (as provided as command line argument) belongs to the "clean" lifecycle? There could be another lifecycle that also has a "clean" phase.

It may be a rule that all phases over all lifecycles must have a unique name. But i don't know.

Comment: AFAIK, this is the rule, yes.

Comment: In Maven there existing only the following three life cycles `clean`, `default` and `site` See https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html

Comment: Yes, but there is no mentioning that phases must have unique names. One could induce that phase names are unique from studying the lifecycle reference. But at least from my point of view this would be guessing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven: Relationship between Lifecycle Phase & Goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038536/maven-relationship-between-lifecycle-phase-goal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Maven there existing only the following three life cycles

1. `clean`
2. `default`
3. `site`

The details are defined in the lifecycle binding of Maven core     https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html

The existing and defined life cycles are defined in the following file:

```
META-INF/plexus/components.xml
```

Comment: My question is not about the lifecycles, but about the phase names. If a specific phase name, such as "clean" may be defined by multiple lifecycles. If some rule forbids this, i'd be a happy camper :)

Comment: The link is generated from Maven core. This means if you would ever change it the build of Maven itself will fail. And yes it will not unique anymore which would make it necessary to somehow make supplemental information given on command line ...which would a really breaking change in Maven...

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you.